# Digital signal to Power Line Communication (PLC)

Tags: mains, dac, power-line-communication

For a hobby project I created my own digital protocol. I use a 16 Volt data bus (16 Volt = 1, 0 Volt = 0). My protocol is A-synchronous, half duplex and uses a transmittion speed of 4800 bits per second. Currently I am looking for a way to transmit my protocol over 230 Volt power lines.

[image]

The above image shows a schematic overview of what I am trying to do. My digital signal  has to be converted and placed on the 230 Volts between the L1 and GND. I then want to be able to take the signal from the power line at any random location and convert it back into the original digital signal. I expect the L1 and GND to be a few hundred meters long. Since the protocol is half-duplex, I also need the receiver to be able to send signals back over the powerline.

Since this is a hobby project I would like to design my own hardware. I looked at different ethernet over powerline adapters to find some schematic examples on how to achieve something like this, but I could not find any clear explanations on how they work. I expect I will need to convert my digital signal to analog and then amplify it to match the 230 Volts.

I would highly appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction. Any schematics of existing modules or new ideas are appreciated.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Search the internet for 'x.10 powerline communication schematic' for an example mains communication standard. It would be much safer to use that sort of existing technology and equipment. I have to warn you that designing circuitry for direct connection to the mains is a dangerous undertaking. It should not be done unless you are experienced in designing for electrical safety at high voltages.

Comment: *Currently I am looking for a way to transmit my protocol over 230 Volt power lines.* The safe and easy route is to convert it to something less custom, packetize it and send it over standard powerline hardware. (I did my master's thesis on the PLC channel: that thing is very strongly cyclostationary. You'll *want* to do packets here, as your error correction will have to deal with the changing badness of the channel and you can't get data through at every instant)

Comment: *… amplify it to match the 230 Volts.* Nope. That would require your transmitter to be able to deliver as much power as the power grid is able to deliver to your house. So that's not going to happen, unless you're having a spare power plant in your attic. You're going to have to modulate higher frequencies with much much less amplitude and recover that at the receiving end. Your 16 V amplitude are already much higher than what you'll usually see on the power line as difference between unmodulated grid sine and sine + data transmission. But yes, you will need to modulate to form an analog

Comment: signal (by the way, your 2400 bd bus *is* analog. It's just slow enough and high-amplitude enough that you can allow yourself the luxury of ignoring the fact that it is); you will then have to demodulate it. Receiving powerline communications is, in the steps required (impedance matching, filtering, sampling, detection, AGC, clock recovery, demodulation, equalization in time and frequency, decision, error correction…) practically the same as receiving very wideband radio signals (all the same problems, just honestly worse).

Comment: You shouldn't use earth as a return for your PLC.